# Write image as the value of sequence file with pyspark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I am using pyspark to write sequence files, the key is image filename and the value is the image representing by bytestring

```
from PIL import Image

def get_image(filename):
 s = StringIO()
 im=io.imread(filename)
 io.imsave(s, im)
 return [(filename, s)]

rdd  =  sc.parallelize(filenames)
rdd.flatMap(get_image).saveAsSequenceFile("/user/myname/output")
```

but pyspark throws an exception which indicates that pickle does not support the format

```
Caused by: net.razorvine.pickle.InvalidOpcodeException: opcode not implemented: OBJ
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:224)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:85)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:98)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SerDeUtil.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SerDeUtil.scala:150)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1298)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1298)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Is this in Spark 2.0? I just ran into the same issue, but I didn't see this issue with Spark 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

The OBJ opcode for pickling is used when you're trying to encode/decode a python class/object for serialization. In my case, I didn't intend to write an object to the sequence file, so the fix for me was just fixing that bug.

As for the overall ecosystem, the problem is that [spark uses Pyrolite 4.13](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/67eef47acfd26f1f0be3e8ef10453514f3655f62/dev/deps/spark-deps-hadoop-2.7#L161) but OBJ encoding/decoding wasn't introduced into the Pyrolite library until [version 4.17](https://github.com/irmen/Pyrolite/releases/tag/pyrolite-4.17). As far as what to do about this, I suppose you have a few options:

1. Convince the spark maintainers, either through a pull request, or github issue, to use a later version of Pyrolite.
2. Build your own version of Spark, using that version of Pyrolite
3. Don't write classes/objects to your sequence files.